# Maximum Thickness for NMO Mounting Surface?

Tags: antenna

How thick can the metal be for a common NMO antenna mount?  I know they're meant for sheet metal but can they go as thick as 1/4"?

Edited to add: 
By "common", I mean NOT the ones designed for extra think applications. If you look on Amazon, or anywhere else, you will see many NMO mounts from many vendors that all look exactly the same. They are the kind I mean. I would like to know how thick the metal can be for one of those.

[image]

Comment: I think it would be better to describe what you're asking about as “common” instead of “standard”. Also, if you include a picture, then people could recognize the mount as one they have and can measure/test for you.

Comment: I agree!  I should have said that in the first place.  I have edited it accordingly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the manufacturer, Larsen, who was under contract to Motorola to design and produce the original NMO mounts:

> The maximum thickness is 2.5mm

Answer (score 1):

How big can the cable be for a "standard" PL-259 connector? The standard specifies the mating interface, not the mounting.

Just as there is no "standard" cable size for a connector, there's no "standard" mounting thickness for an NMO mount. The only thing standardized is the part the antenna screws into.

So to answer your question, you'll need to read the mechanical specifications for a specific mount. They come in all kinds. And yes, some can [accommodate thicknesses greater than 1/4"](http://www.americanradiosupply.com/opek-nmo-3-nmo-to-uhf-female-so-239-adapter-2-inch-long/).

Comment: @Lance "How big is a sandwich?" "There are many kinds of sandwiches. Which one?" "Look around, there are many that look exactly the same. You know, the normal kind. They're standard." What kind of answer are you expecting? Look around: there are *tons* of NMO mounts available, for every conceivable situation. Find one that fits your needs.

Comment: I have edited my question to change "standard" to "common".  I still think you're being a bit nit-picky here, because I believe my meaning was clear.  But if it really wasn't, it should be now.

Comment: @Lance The meaning of your question was never unclear. It doesn't change the fact that even among NMO mounts that look like the one in your picture, there are many that are similar. Or that there are mounts that will accommodate 1/4 inch thicknesses. If that's what you need, then buy one that fits.

Comment: If you understood my meaning all along then you should have just answered instead of busting my chops about it.  The "common" NMO connectors sold ANYWHERE do not list their max thickness EXCEPT the ones that are specifically stated to be 1", 2", etc., which I excluded.  If you are really familiar with NMO mounts, I would think you would know this.

Comment: NMO = New MOtorola.  Somewhere, there is a technical drawing that specifies the dimensions of every aspect of this device.  But unfortunately, that document is not published so it isn't easy to find. Any NMO mount made and sold by anyone has to meet these specs or it isn't an NMO mount.

The max thickness of a standard NMO mount is not something that will vary much from maker to maker.  It is a specific measurement.

Comment: Based on everything you've said, the best I can figure is that you don't really understand my question.  That's okay.  "I don't know" is always an acceptable answer.  But there is no reason AT ALL for you to trash my question like you're trying to do.

If you don't know, then just move along.

Comment: @Lance Speaking as a moderator — please don't attribute adversarial motives to other users so fast. “They're all different”, or in general, **“What you're looking for doesn't exist”, is a legitimate answer to a question.** It may be _factually wrong_ in any particular case, but it's not an _attack._

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

They can mount on surfaces a little thicker than 2.5mm, though I suspect the exact thickness varies by manufacturer. I was successful in mounting to a .125" surface (3.2mm). The constraint was not so much the mounting surface thickness, but rather snaking the connector through the 0.75" mounting hole in a too-thick plate. I had to add some cutouts to the mounting hole to get it to fit.

The question also asked if they can go as thick as 1/4".  For a "common" NMO antenna mount, no.  Thk 1/8" is about the upper limit --and I do not recommend trying it-- due to the clearance in the non-adjustable section.  As mentioned by others, though, it is easy enough to buy NMO-compatible mounts which work with thicker surfaces.